# How do I change the certificate of a Shibboleth service provider?

Tags: sso, saml, xml

How do I change the certificate of a Shibboleth service provider? I have an existing identity provider (IDP) and service provider (SP) and I need to replace the certificate with a Verisign signed cert. I am testing with a self-signed cert created with the Shibboleth etc/shibboleth/keygen.bat.

I have added the new cert & key as a standby CredentialResolver in shibboleth2.xml for the SP:

```
<CredentialResolver keyName="Standby" type="File" key="D:/tmp/sp-key-qa.pem" certificate="D:/tmp/sp-cert-qa.pem"/>
```

I have updated the metadata for the IDP by adding the cert in the metadata file:

relying-party.xml:

```
    <metadata:MetadataProvider id="CMSMd" xsi:type="metadata:ResourceBackedMetadataPro$
        <metadata:MetadataResource xsi:type="resource:FilesystemResource" file="/usr/s$
    </metadata:MetadataProvider>
```

metadata.xml:

```
<KeyDescriptor>
  <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
      <ds:X509Certificate>
MIIDMDCCAhigAwIBAgIJAJ1BXaNNWMHhMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMCAxHjAcBgNV
...
```

And it works up to that point. However, when I comment out the old certificate from the metadata on the IDP and restart, then it fails.

metadata.xml:

```
<!-- Old cert
    <KeyDescriptor>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
MIIFjjCCA3agAwIBAgICAsowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgaAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
...
```

When I try to access the protected URL, it redirects correctly to the IDP, I authenticate, it redirects to the SP at the URL /Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/Artifact?SAMLart=AAQAAilR... and fails with 'Internal Server Error. Please contact the site administrator.' in the browser.

In the IDP log, it says

> 10:14:12.124 - ERROR [org.opensaml.ws.security.provider.ClientCertAuthRule:156] - Authentication via client certificate failed for context presenter entity ID urn:company:cms
>
> 10:14:12.154 - DEBUG [PROTOCOL_MESSAGE:64] -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap11:Envelope xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap11:Body>
  <saml2p:ArtifactResponse xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_6cbe5f5c3327d6bea5223322eb637a75" InResponseTo="_d7eda74f5805219b22c4e5be2fe8bbb7" IssueInstant="2012-07-17T14:14:12.143Z" Version="2.0">
     <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">urn:company:sso:idp</saml2:Issuer>
     <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder">
           <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied"/>
        </saml2p:StatusCode>
        <saml2p:StatusMessage>Message did not meet security requirements</saml2p:StatusMessage>
     </saml2p:Status>
  </saml2p:ArtifactResponse>
</soap11:Body>
</soap11:Envelope>
```

In the SP log, it says:

```
<13>Jul 17 10:13:38 CMSMACHINE01 [apache-error]: [Tue Jul 17 10:13:38 2012] [error] [client 172.17.87.25] client denied by server configuration: D:/Packages/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
<-5>[shibd] ERROR [[1]] OpenSAML.SOAPClient - SOAP client detected a SAML error: (urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder) (Message did not meet security requirements)
<-5>[apache-shibd] ERROR [[9888] shib_handler] Shibboleth.Listener - remoted message returned an error: Identity provider returned a SAML error in response to artifact.
<-5>[apache-shibd] ERROR [[9888] shib_handler] Shibboleth.Apache - Identity provider returned a SAML error in response to artifact.
<-5>[apache-shibd] ERROR [[9888] shib_handler] Shibboleth.ServiceProvider - sendError could not process error template ()
<13>Jul 17 10:14:12 CMSMACHINE01 [apache-error]: [Tue Jul 17 10:14:12 2012] [error] [client 172.17.87.25] Identity provider returned a SAML error in response to artifact., referer: https://sso.dev.company.com/idp/Authn/BB
```

Please help. I have a feeling there is a security policy setting somewhere, but I can't find any documentation on it nor any setting in the configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one CredentialResolver can be used in the SP shibboleth2.xml, since the SP metadata on the IDP was updated manually.

Also, this was required on the IDP web server, which is behind Apache, to avoid cryptic errors.

SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca